# Freeze Google Map until user clicks

Tags: google-maps

I'm fairly new to Google Maps API, so spare the flame :)

How do I disable the controls of a google map(i.e. scroll, drag etc.) untill a user clicks on the map itself? I want the user to be able to scroll down on a page without ending up scrolling on the map. Due to design decisions the map appears in a position often hit by a scrolling user.

I don't want to use a static map, since I still want the user to be able to use the map, when he feels the need to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map has [methods](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2) to enable and disable dragging. You could just create the map with dragging disabled, and call enableDragging() whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a mouse click listener to the map div, which calls [enableScrollWheelZoom](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.enableScrollWheelZoom).  You could also destroy the listener after it's called the first time.

jQuery example:

```
$("#mapDiv").click(function() {
    map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
});
```

The API reference indicates that scroll wheel zoom is disabled by default - if it's enabled because of any other calls you've made (such as `setUIToDefault`), just disable it first.